# IndexOutOfBoundsException during assigning arrays

Tags: java, android

I am doing a time management app in android and I have activities and tags class included in it. Every activity has a tag and in Statistics fragment I want to make a pie chart by using the information: how many activities user did with a specific tag. So for that I have included achartengine lib to my project and I am sure that it works (tried it with default inputs) but ı need the info that user entered. So I took that information and tried to assign those in arrays I created but during this process in my for loop I take an error =>

> 12-21 22:56:47.330 6861-6861/com.beter.timehole E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL        EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                     Process: com.beter.timehole, PID: 6861
>                                                                     java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
>                                                                         at
>   com.beter.timehole.fragments.StatisticsFragment.initData(StatisticsFragment.java:112)

So I showed where the exception points in for loop any help is appreciated.

```
package com.beter.timehole.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.chart.BarChart.Type;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries;
import org.achartengine.model.SeriesSelection;
import org.achartengine.renderer.DefaultRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.SimpleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.chart.BarChart.Type;
import org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.DefaultRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.SimpleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;


import com.beter.timehole.R;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;


public class StatisticsFragment extends Fragment {

private View mView;
private GraphicalView mGraphView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.statistics_fragment, container, false);
    mView = rootView;
    initData();
    return rootView;
}



private void initData() {
    ArrayList<com.beter.timehole.core.Activity> activitiesArrayList = new ArrayList<com.beter.timehole.core.Activity>();
    activitiesArrayList  = readActivitiesFromFile();

    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    int tagNumber=0;
    for(int i=0;i<activitiesArrayList.size();i++)
    {
        if(i==0) {
            temp.add(activitiesArrayList.get(i).getTag().getTagName());
            tagNumber ++;
        }
        else if(temp.contains(activitiesArrayList.get(i).getTag().getTagName()))
        {}
        else
        {
            temp.add(activitiesArrayList.get(i).getTag().getTagName());
            tagNumber ++;
        }
    }



    String[] codename = new String[tagNumber];
    Double[] values = new Double[tagNumber];
    String[] colors = new String[tagNumber];
    int j=1;
    for(int i=0;i<activitiesArrayList.size();i++)
    {
            if(codename.length == 0) {
                codename[0] = activitiesArrayList.get(i).getTag().getTagName();
                values[0]=1.0;
            }
            else if(Arrays.asList(codename).contains(activitiesArrayList.get(i).getTag().getTagName()))
            {
                int index = java.util.Arrays.asList(codename).indexOf(activitiesArrayList.get(i).getTag().getTagName());
                values[index]=values[index]+1;
            }
            else {
                codename[j] = activitiesArrayList.get(i).getTag().getTagName();// It is where the error points(line no:112)
                int index = java.util.Arrays.asList(codename).indexOf(activitiesArrayList.get(i).getTag().getTagName());
                values[index]=1.0;
                j++;
            }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<codename.length;i++)
    {
        int integer =(int) (Math.random()*1000000);
        String color = "#" + integer;
        colors[i]= color;
    }

    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Android Platform Version");
    int length = codename.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        series.add(codename[i], values[i]);

    DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        seriesRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor(colors[i]));
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);

    }

    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(60);
    renderer.setChartTitle("Android Platform Version");
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(30);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.GRAY);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(30);

    drawChart(series, renderer);
}
private ArrayList<com.beter.timehole.core.Activity> readActivitiesFromFile(){
    ArrayList<com.beter.timehole.core.Activity> activitiesFromFile = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        FileInputStream activityFileInputStream = getContext().openFileInput("activityobjects.dat");
        ObjectInputStream activityObjectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(activityFileInputStream);
        activitiesFromFile = (ArrayList<com.beter.timehole.core.Activity>)activityObjectInputStream.readObject();
        activityObjectInputStream.close();
        activityFileInputStream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return activitiesFromFile;
}

private void drawChart(CategorySeries series, DefaultRenderer renderer) {

    if (null == mGraphView) {
        mGraphView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(getActivity(), series, renderer);
        RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.graph_container);
        container.addView(mGraphView);
    }
    else
        mGraphView.repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: According to your error message, it would appear that you are trying to access the 3rd position (index `2`) in the `codename` array, but `codename`'s size is only `2`.  It's really up to you to step through your program and figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Yes I know but I could not figure it out and this project is for tomorrow, so I thought maybe it is another problem that I can not see and decided to upload it here. However I am still thinking about the problem if anyone could help me, it would be so nice. Thank you.

Comment: Why you set j = 1 , codename.length = activitiesArrayList.size() + 1 or not ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems pretty straight forward. The index points outside of the arraylist. You could use the iterator pattern to help avoid an OutOfBounds exception, but other than that I suggest simply issuing a break point at the point of the exception, and make sure you are comparing the right values to signal the end of an array.